# Qt SIGABRT alternative message?

Tags: c++, qt, sigabrt

I'm using Qt5.9, a simple check:

```
      assert(pobjNode != NULL);
```

Will cause the Qt Signal Received error dialog to be displayed which doesn't give any helpful information about where the problem is or what it is.

Is there a way to replace this useless information with something a bit more helpful?

What I'm thinking of is a way to set-up the dialog to display what could be an error in the event of an error.

Comment: On which operating system? Why using the `gdb` debugger is not enough?

Comment: Ubuntu, I don't want to use the debugger for everything...its far easier to throw in an assert and run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q_ASSERT` is a custom assert macro which supposedly enhances the standard `assert` function.

The error message is handled by  **[`qFatal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFatal)**, which can behave slightly better on some platforms than the standard assert macro. For example on Windows it will trigger the Visual Studio debugger at the point where the assertion fails instead of just calling `abort()`.

You can also **redirect** the output of Qt error message functions such as `qFatal`to your custom message handler ( with [qInstallMessageHandler()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) ). It can be useful for example if you want to redirect the errors message to a file.

Also note that `Q_ASSERT` is disabled with the macro `QT_NO_DEBUG`(while `assert` is disabled by `NDEBUG`) : this can be used to separate your asserts between Qt-related code and the rest.

`Q_ASSERT_X` Prints the message what together with the location where, the source file name and line number if test is false.
Prints the message what together with the location where, the source file name and line number if test is false.
Example:

```
 // File: div.cpp
    #include <QtGlobal>
    int divide(int a, int b)
      {
          Q_ASSERT_X(b != 0, "divide", "division by zero");
          return a / b;
      }
```

to read more on [test and debug](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/testing-and-debugging.html).

Comment: at the bottom of post there is a link on test and debug from Qt docs, you may read it and find nice workarounds. any way if you want to have more on this let me know

Comment: hmmm....Having just gone through all the code and replaced instances of assert with Q_ASSERT_X, the error displayed in the dialog is not changed and remains as useless as ever...."Signal Received, The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. "

Comment: If you are using qt creator and gdb goto Tools->options->debugger in Gdb extend tab mark stop when qFatal() is called

Comment: Ok, I see the message in the console, what I was expecting was to see the message in the dialog?

Comment: Actually It depends on debugger and QtCreator My guess is this message box dialog is designed to just notify operation system signals to debugger and you should manage this your self by check call stack.

Comment: You can disable it , look for **show a message box when receiving a signal** in GDB tab of debugger dialog but, I don't suggest it.

Comment: I agree, the idea was to replace it with something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You might define your own `MY_ASSERT` macro. On Linux it could even call another function which uses Glibc [backtrace functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) or Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) library (provided your code is compiled with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information using `g++ -g`) and perhaps display such information in a modal dialog, or on *stderr*. However, it should probably not return. Read also about [Qt and Unix signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

But `assert` detects a bug which you should correct. Try hard to avoid shipping code with such programmer bugs.

On Linux, the usual `assert` -it is a macro defined in `/usr/include/assert.h`- will call on failure `__assert_fail` (in your C library, but you might redefine it yourself) which would indirectly call `abort` which indirectly makes a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) which you can inspect post-mortem using the `gdb` debugger. You only need to enable core dumps (using `ulimit -c` builtin in your bash terminal).

Comment: Starynkevich sounds nice post +1 , can be useful in Linux